# Часть кода работает медленно

Tags: java, оптимизация, инспекция-кода

Один метод работает слишком медленно(около 1,5 сек, длина текста - 460 символов; необходимо как можно меньше). Вполне возможно в результате того, что в коде ошибка. Может ли работать быстрее код с таким функционалом?

```
public static double calcIndexTrigrams(String str) throws IOException {
        int nG=3;
        double index = 0;
        File file = new File(TRIGRAMS);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_16));
        String line;
        for (int c = 0; c < (str.length()-nG); c++) {
            reader.mark((int) file.length());
            while((line = reader.readLine())!= null){
                if (str.substring(c,c+nG).equalsIgnoreCase(line.substring(0,nG))) {
                    index+=(Double.parseDouble(line.substring(nG+1)));
                    break;}}
            reader.reset();}
        return index;}
```

Comment: Во первых, лучше показать полный пример. Во вторых, нужно дать определение, что такое "непозволительно долго" и сколько в идеале оно должно работать.

Comment: Ну а что за алгоритм криптографии? Возможно именно в этом и причина.

Comment: @kovadim спасибо, исправил вопрос.

Comment: Первое, что я бы сделал, это  развернул циклы. Цикл по файлу должен быть первым, а цикл по строке - внутри.